# Why is user.inisrole false after token renew?

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

@If (User.IsInRole ("Admin")) returns true when I login to the site. However, when I buy a new token with reflesh token, @if (User.IsInRole ("Admin")) returns false. I host the token in the cookie.
**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, opts =>
            {
                var tokenOptions = Configuration.GetSection("TokenOption").Get<CustomTokenOption>();
                opts.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters()
                {
                    ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience[0],
                    IssuerSigningKey = SignService.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(tokenOptions.SecurityKey),
                    RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
                };
                opts.SaveToken = true;
                opts.Events = new JwtBearerEvents();
                opts.Events.OnMessageReceived = context => 
                {

                    if (context.Request.Cookies.ContainsKey("X-Access-Token"))
                    {
                        context.Token = context.Request.Cookies["X-Access-Token"];
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                };
            })
            .AddCookie(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly=true;
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

**Reflesh token**

```
private async Task<JsonConvertModelNoList<TokenDto>> TokenIsValid(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("X-Access-Token");
            _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("X-Refresh-Token");
            var refToken = new RefreshTokenDto();
            refToken.Token = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["X-Refresh-Token"];
            var refTokenResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://localhost:44320/api/Auth/CreateTokenByRefreshToken", refToken,
                new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()).ConfigureAwait(false);

            JsonConvertModelNoList<TokenDto> result = null;
            result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonConvertModelNoList<TokenDto>>(await refTokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            if (refTokenResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

                if (result.StatusCode == 200)
                {
                    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("X-Access-Token", result.Data.AccessToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict });
                    _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("X-Refresh-Token", result.Data.RefreshToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = true, SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict });
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    var errorResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonConvertModelError>(result.Error.ToString());
                    result.Error = errorResult.errors;
                    return result;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var errorResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonConvertModelError>(result.Error.ToString());
                result.Error = errorResult.errors;
                return result;
            }
           
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea how to go about it? My English is a little bad. Sorry.

Comment: It seems that it is rather a problem of the method which issues a new access token based on the refresh token. Probably that method does not add proper role claim to the access token. You should check that part first.

Comment: Actually the role is being added. When I refresh the page again, @If (User.IsInRole ("Admin")) returns true.

Comment: But maybe it is added in the method which issues an access token during login, but in the method which issues an access token during refresh (I don't know if these are two different methods in your code). What I'm saying is that you should make absolutely sure that you get an access token with the same data inside, whether you issue or refresh the token.